# how to create one-to-one related user roles with djoser

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have a Custom user model and 4 role models

```
class User(models.Model):
is_student = True
is_teacher = True
is_staff= True
is_admin = True

Class Student(models.Model):
   user = models.Foreignkey(User) 

Class Teacher(models.Model):
   user = models.Foreignkey(User) 

Class Admin(models.Model):
   user = models.Foreignkey(User) 

Class Staff(models.Model):
   user = models.Foreignkey(User)
```

I'm using djoser for User authentication.

Now what I want is when somebody POST to

`'api/v1/{role name}/register'`
User is created automatically and so is the role model's object.

Currently I know that only POST request to '/users' will create the user in djoser and I have to use `post_save` signal when `is_{role} field` in user model is true, to save any role model object.

I'm trying to use a nested serializer but that is not compatible with djoser.